# Equality of strings in vectors

Tags: lisp, elisp

I've defined a function in elisp to find the index of a list in a vector:

```
(defun vposition (e v)  
   (letrec  
      ((f (lambda (e v i)  
             (if (equal e (elt v i))  
                 i  
                 (f e v (+ i 1))))))  
      (f e v 0)))
```

If I use it on numbers it's fine, but with strings, e.g. `(vposition "bar" ["foo" "bar" "thing"])`, I get an error:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument number-or-marker-p "bar")
  =("bar" "foo")
```

If I do, say, `(vposition 3 [1 2 3])`, it works as expected, and `(equal "bar" "foo")` works, too, so I can't isolate where the problem is. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that your calls to `f` don't call the function held in the local variable `f`, but some other function `f` which you presumably defined earlier by accident (and that function uses `=` instead of `equal`).  When I try your code and example I get a different error:

```
Symbol's function definition is void: f
```

You can fix your code easily with:

```
(defun vposition (e v)  
  (letrec  
      ((f (lambda (e v i)  
            (if (equal e (elt v i))  
                i  
              (funcall f e v (+ i 1))))))
    (funcall f e v 0)))
```

Of course, recursion like that tends to work inefficiently in Elisp because the Elisp implementation is too naive, so you may want to use a `while` loop instead.

Answer (score 0):

This one works:

```
(defun vposition (e v)
  (cl-labels ((f (e v i)
                (if (equal e (elt v i))
                    i
                  (f e v (+ i 1)))))
    (f e v 0)))
```

Comment: Where's ```cl-labels``` defined? It's not in ```cl```. Also, is there a reason ```letrec``` breaks and ```cl-labels``` doesn't?

Comment: The file is `cl-macs.el`, but you get it with `(require 'cl-lib)`.
`cl-lib` is the tasteful way to use cl in Emacs, I guess.